# what is the meaning of this line in android samples?

Tags: android, android-layout

what is the meaning of line

> " and add the corresponding **activity** tags to the Android Manifest
>   file"

in the tab example on 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

under step 2.

i added the activity tags and it's still dont work

```
 <activity android:name=".ArtistsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity android:name=".AlbumsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" /> 
        <activity android:name=".SongsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: point 7. just without NoTitleBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you create a new activity in android, you have to add an activity tag to your android manifest file.  Take a peek at this example,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Edit:  in your specific example that you are following, you would have to add ArtistsActivity to the manifest in an <activity></activity> tag

Answer (score 1):

It means add your activities to your manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".HelloTabWidget">
```

Comment: Each time you create an activity it has to be added to the manifest if you plan on making use of the class.